# Why doesn't this escape sequence work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, escaping

I'm playing with `\N{name}` *(character named name in the Unicode database)* but it doesn't work.

Typing this code:

```
print "\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"
```

or this variant:

```
print u"\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"
```

I get the result:

```
\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}
```

**in both cases.**

What is the problem? Why didn't I get a character from the Unicode database?

Comment: Why do you have `\N` at the start of your question and `/N` in the rest of your examples?

Comment: I edited. I'm sorry, just silly mistakes.

Comment: But `print  u"\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA}"` would work? Did you actually use \N or /N?

Comment: I get an error - UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xd8' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284269/why-doesnt-python-recognize-my-utf-8-encoded-source-file/14284404#14284404 it is down to your terminal encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\N` is the proper escape sequence. You have to use a backslash `\`.

Also see : [UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2010': character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382686/unicodeencodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-encode-character-u2010-character-m)