# BeautifulSoup encoding.bytes has no attribute called find_all?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

```
 `self.urlOpen=urllib.request.urlopen("http://facebook.com")
  self.content=self.urlOpen.read()
  soup=BeautifulSoup(self.content,"html5lib")
  self.links=soup.find_all("a")`
```

> 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position....

so when i try to encode the soup variable
    `self.urlOpen=urllib.request.urlopen("http://facebook.com")
      self.content=self.urlOpen.read()
      soup=BeautifulSoup(self.content,"html5lib")
      soup=soup.encode("utf-8")
      self.links=soup.find_all("a")`

> 'bytes' object has no attribute called find_all

I have tried
`self.urlOpen=urllib.request.urlopen("http://facebook.com")
      self.content=self.urlOpen.read()
      soup=BeautifulSoup(self.content.decode("utf-8","ignore"),"html5lib")
      self.links=soup.find_all("a")`

but same error occurs

Then how should I encode it?

Comment: Include full tracebacks when asking for debugging help.

Comment: Also, `soup.encode('utf-8')` just [creates a byte-string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#non-pretty-printing) out of the HTML, which of course has no method `find_all()`.

Comment: You're probably suffering from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284269/why-doesnt-python-recognize-my-utf-8-encoded-source-file): your terminal can't handle the output instead of any problems with beautifulsoup etc.

Comment: thank you @llja Everila.that was breif.but how should i encode to prevent such error?

Comment: Iam using `Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: yes.Iam runnig this in the cmd shell

Comment: yes.I have Visual studio 2015.But there was problem importing the libraries so iam using cmd

Comment: Actually iam trying this to print all the links in a text file?will it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the issue?
`find_all` shouldn't be throwing an encoding error, and you shouldn't be calling `encode` on a `bs4.BeautifulSoup` object, as `encode` returns a bytestring - not a soup! - so you can't call `find_all` on it.

Are you using `soup.prettify()` anywhere? In that case, that is probably the line throwing an error. Please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: but my question is how to encode it so that i can call find_all

Comment: You *should* be able to use find_all. Please post a representative example of your code and the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: `import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
urlOpen=urllib.request.urlopen("http://facebook.com")
content=self.urlOpen.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html5lib")
links=soup.find_all("a")
f=open("links.txt","w+")
for link in links:
    href=link.get("href")
    text=link.text
    f.write(text + "--\t" + self.href + "\n")
f.flush()
f.close()
 `

Comment: First off, you're setting `href` to `link.get("href")` but later inserting `self.href` instead of `href` into the string - that should throw an error.

Second, it's probably `f.write` that's throwing the error. Try opening the file using `f = open("links,txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')`.

Third, your example works just fine for me.

Comment: ssorry my bad.self was a typo.but i have to try encoding='utf-8'.

Comment: Thanks that worked!!`f=open("link.txt","w+",encoding="utf-8")`.