# Ignoring certain characters while looping through CSV rows

Tags: python-3.x

Using this code to try and print each row in a csv:

```
import csv

f = open('export.csv')
csv_f = csvkit.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    print(row)
```

Unfortunately, the csv file contains the character ® in multiple lines, which results in the following error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 27: character maps to <undefined>`

I have searched through other answers to similar problems and tried using different encodings, but unfortunately can't quite wrap my head around it enough to make it work. The CSV file seems to be in UTF-8 format, or at least that's what OpenOffice Calc says when I open up the file in Windows.

Is there any way for me to print the rows while "ignoring" the ® character so that no error is returned? Any alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated, too.

Comment: works for me. can you try `print([x.decode("latin-1") for x in row])` ?

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Sorry. `print([x.encode("latin-1") for x in row])`

Comment: Sounds like a Windows console error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284269/why-doesnt-python-recognize-my-utf-8-encoded-source-file

Comment: Zero Piraeus - it was indeed a Windows console error. I switched the codepage to 65001 (`chcp 65001` in windows console) and ran the script afterwards - worked perfectly. Thanks for the help. (Note to others: you need to run this command again each time you restart the windows console.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter some "unprintable/weird" chars you can do this:

```
row = ["aaaaa \xae bbbbb","foo"]

filtered_row = ["".join(c if ord(c)<128 else "." for c in s) for s in row]
print(filtered_row)
```

result (all strange chars have been replaced by dots):

```
['aaaaa . bbbbb', 'foo']
```